# Quelle est la différence de sens des phrases négatives suivantes ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation

Dans le cas suivant, est-il nécessaire d'employer « de » ou puis-je dire également « un » ?
Est- ce que le sens change si j'emploie « de » ou « un » ?

A. Dans ces phrases, le **COD** est nié:

1. Il ne voulait pas avoir **de** chien, il voulait avoir un chat.
2. Il ne voulait pas avoir **un** chien, il voulait avoir un chat.

B. Dans ces phrases, le **verbe** est nié:

1. Il ne voulait pas **avoir** **un** **chien**, il voulait **caresser** un chien.
2. Il ne voulait pas **avoir** **de** **chien**, il voulait **caresser** un chien.

Comment: Selon moi, les 4 phrases sont correctes et portent le même sens deux par deux. Question de style, je préfère l'emploi de "de" qui évite de répéter "un".

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais que :

- `A.1` est plus idiomatique que `A.2`, donc à préférer ;
- `A.2` peut sembler porter l'attention sur le **nombre** de chiens, comme dans cet exemple :

  *Il ne voulait pas avoir **un** chien, mais **deux**.*

Comment: Dans les deux cas l'emploie de "de" au lien de "un" indique un nombre indéterminé.

Answer (score 3):

[Cette ressource](http://gabrielwyler.com/page400.html) traite de manière exhaustive le sujet. Grossièrement, si la négation porte sur l'ensemble du complément d'objet, en traduisant un manque, une absence, alors on utilise "de". Sinon, "un". Dans les exemples suivants :

> Il ne voulait pas avoir **de** chien, il voulait avoir un chat.

La négation porte sur "avoir de chien" : il refuse d'avoir un chien, il ne le supporte pas. Il y a absence de volonté d'avoir un chien. Le sens est général, et le contexte ajoute qu'il préfère un chat.

> Il ne voulait pas avoir **un** chien, il voulait avoir un chat.

La négation porte sur "un chien" : on insiste sur le fait qu'il veut quelque chose, mais ce n'est pas "un chien". Le sens est identique à la phrase précédente, mis à part l'insistance sur le fait que "un chien" n'est pas l'objet convoité. Si ce n'est pas "un chien", c'est donc plusieurs chiens ou un autre animal.

La négation aurait aussi pu porter sur "avoir" si la suite de la phrase n'avait pas précisé qu'il voulait un chat. La phrase aurait pu être :

> Il ne voulait pas avoir un chien, il voulait s'amuser avec un chien.

On retrouve donc l'exemple B.1. Quant à B.2, cela désigne une nouvelle fois que toute l'action "avoir un chien" est niée, et le contexte ajoute qu'il aurait voulu caresser un chien. Par exemple :

> Le voyou s'est introduit dans le chenil. Non, il n'a rien volé. Il ne voulait pas de chien. Il voulait juste caresser un chien.